# Get user control method and properties from static page method

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax

So I have an ASP.NET user control that is using jQuery AJAX to call a method. Here's the jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Default.aspx/AdvertClick',
    data: '{"name":"test"}',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Because it needs to call a static web method, I have the AdvertClick method in the Default.aspx page:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string AdvertClick(string name)
{
    return "";
}
```

In my AdvertClick method, I'm taking in a string value. I have a lot of data and methods in my user control that I need to access in order to do something with that string value. But because the method in my page is static, I can't access anything from my user control without creating a new instance of the control.

Is there any way I can access the user control methods? Should I try a different AJAX technique? I hate that I have to call a method on the page, which then needs to access data from my control.

Comment: sounds like you need to rethink your design. web methods shouldnt need to care about things on the page, it should be able to make decisions based on only the parameters (ie string name). consider either passing more info to the web method, or using an updatepanel.

Comment: I agree with RPM1984. Though I would be really sad to see you move from using JQuery for AJAX to an updatepanel.

Answer (score 0):

Move your static method AdvertClick code into a class, and then call it from your web method, and the control on the page. The work could be done in a class, so both can access it.

What exactly does the control do?